# LSTM with different timestep when predicting

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Let's say I  have some timeseries data with shape `(80,27)` which means 80 timesteps and 27 features. I want to train the following network in a way to predict each timestep separately and not the 80 timesteps together because in the prediction phase my input shape is `(1,27)`  each timestep `t` until I reach `t = 80` .
So I have to find a way to predict 80 samples-timesteps of `(1,27)` without losing backpropagation through time when training.

Any suggestions?

```
def Model():
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(80,27))
    
    
    x = layers.Conv1D(64,kernel_size=5,activation="relu",padding="same")(inputs)
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(256,return_sequences=True))(x)
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(256,return_sequences=True))(x)
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(256,return_sequences=True))(x)
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128,return_sequences=True))(x)
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128,return_sequences=True))(x)
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128,return_sequences=True))(x)

    
    x = layers.Dense(512,activation="selu")(x)
    x = layers.Dense(256,activation="selu")(x)
    
    x = layers.Dense(2)(x)
   
    
    return keras.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two different questions to answer:

- If you want a variable number of timesteps, simply set that size in the input shape to `None`; that is, `inputs = layers.Input(shape=(None, 27))`. The RNN will then be "unrolled" dynamically at training and testing time. (There might be some performance degradation but that is the price to pay.)
- Both during training and prediction you still need to pass all of the timesteps of the timeseries. That is because you have a Bidirectional RNN in this case. For a `one-directional' RNN, I seem to remember that there is an option that allows you to obtain make invocations stateful by explicitly passing the previous context as input and having the output state returned as an output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!.For the second part  you mean setting `stateful=True` might help solving the problem(In one-directional RNN)?If so , Do I need a stateful model both during training and predicting or just on the prediction  phase?

Comment: `stateful` seems to be that the layer itself keeps the state between batches (indefinitely), and I would assume that would apply during training and testing. I suggest looking at `return_state` class argument and `initial_state` call argument, if you want to have that degree of control.